# Javascript adding multiple values to a property

Tags: javascript

I defined a object, where I have added property "Items". I have that data inside a .each function, but it doesn't add all of that data with commas. 1,2,3 it just switches it out. What am I doing wrong?

```
var data = {};
    $('.beauty').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.selected').each(function(){
            data.Items = $(this).data('id');
        });
        $('.chosenTeam').each(function(){
            data.Team = $(this).data('team');
        });
        console.log(data);
```

Comment: There is nothing more to show

Comment: I recommend to read a tutorial about [data structures in JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html).

Answer (score 0):

Data properties don't store multiple values. If you want that behavior, then the property should store an array or an object. And, if that were the case, you wouldn't just assign a new value because (as you've found out) that just overwrites the old value, you'd need to `push` the data into that array (for example) or add a new property to the object.

```js
// Here, were have a basic object with a single property (users)
// and that property has the ability to store multiple values 
// because it is intialized to store an array
var myObject = {users : []};

// For demonstration, we'll append new values into 
// the array stored in the users property

// This is just an example of a data source that we'll want to draw from
// In reality, this could be any data structure
var userArray = ["Mary", "Joe", "John", "Alice", "Judy", "Steve"];

userArray.forEach(function(user){
  // The most important thing is to note that we are not trying to
  // set the users property equal to anything (that would wipe out
  // its old value in favor of the new value). We are appending new
  // data into the object that the property is storing. 
  myObject.users.push(user);
});


console.log(myObject.users);

// Now, if I want to change one of the values stored in the users 
// property, I wouldn't just set the users property equal to that
// new value because that would wipe out the entire array currently
// stored there. We need to updated one of the values in the data 
// structure that is stored in the property:
myObject.users[3] = "Scott";  // Change the 4th user to "Scott"
console.log(myObject.users);
```

Comment: Hmm, I wanted to use arrays, but seems like I'm that stupid that I couldn't find a way how to add a property to array.

Comment: Well data properties for being a string, are able to store any stringified data - thus all data as well.

Comment: @Lain Technically true, but in practice, why would you want to do this when arrays exist?  Storing data a pure strings is great for data transmission (via serialization), but data stored in arrays can be serialized with no hassle when the array is in an object using JSON.

Comment: @Scott Marcus: Correct. That was no complaint at all - just additional information. Using data-attributes is kinda common aswell and there a man does not have the freedom of choice.

Comment: That seems to be a great way, but is there a chance to add it like. items: 1,2,3,4, without making the array there?

Comment: You can add any values into an array that you like and they can come from any source you have available to you. Me showing how to populate one array with the names of users stored in another array is just an example - - the data has to come from somewhere.

Comment: But, you do need an array stored in the property to be able to properly store multiple values in it.